# Multithreading in Hibernate environment does not working

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions, entitymanager

I want to write parallel into database in J2EE.
In DB, there are some triggers fired which checks data consistency, that's why I want to run it parallel.

Important is that same transaction is used, because in case of an error of any thread the transaction should be rollbacked and no partially data is persisted.

1. This is not working parallel. Maybe using of parallel multiple entity managers inside a transaction is not possible?

   ```
    @Stateless
    @Local
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
    public class ParallelBean {

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    private ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "BASE_")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void writeParallel() {
            UserTransaction beginTransaction = sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
            beginTransaction.begin();
            Map<Integer, EntityManager> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
                em.joinTransaction();
                map.put(i, em);
            }
            final List<Future<?>> futureElements = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                final int a = i;
                futureElements.add(executor.submit(() -> {
                    EntityManager entityManager = map.get(a);
                    threadLocal.set(entityManager);
                    createEntity();
                }));
            }

            readResults(futureElements);
            beginTransaction.commit();
        }

        @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
        public void createEntity() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException {
            DummyBusinessEntity newEntity = new DummyBusinessEntity ();
            threadLocal.get().persist(newEntity);
        }
    }
   ```
2. This is working parallel, but makes a commit after each insert which leads in case of error to inconsistent data

   ```
    @Stateless
    @Local
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
    public class ParallelBean {

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "BASE_")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void writeParallel() {
            UserTransaction beginTransaction = sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
            beginTransaction.begin();

            final List<Future<?>> futureElements = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                final int a = i;
                futureElements.add(executor.submit(() -> {
                    createEntity();
                }));
            }

            readResults(futureElements);
            beginTransaction.commit();
        }

        @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
        public void createEntity() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException {
            DummyBusinessEntity newEntity = new DummyBusinessEntity ();
            dummyDao.persistData(newEntity);
        }
    }

    @Stateless
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    @Local
    public class DummyDAO {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BASE_", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
        protected EntityManager em;


        public void persistData(DummyBE entity) {
            em.persist(entity);
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried batch inserts instead of writing in parallel?

Comment: No, I will give a try. But how can I tell the entityManager which is injected by annotation to make batch inserts?

Comment: You are probably looking for this tutorial - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update.